# Insert data to a datagridview manually with an added column

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I wanted to insert values inside my datagridview by using this:

```
For Each rows As DataGridViewRow In dgView.Rows
    rows.Cells("Ave").Value = Format(Val(dgView.Rows(0).Cells("Qty Issued")) / countMonths).ToString
Next
```

But there's this error: "Argument 'Expression' cannot be converted to type 'DataGridViewTextBoxCell'."

Here is the scenario:
I got a datagridview populated by data from a database. I programmatically added column name "Ave" then I wanted to get the average of one of the column and place it to the added column "Ave" using a loop. I'm open to suggestions by the way.

Thanks to all who helped, I figured it out after a day or so. This is the new code I used:

```
For Each rows As DataGridViewRow In dgView.Rows
            ave = rows.Cells("Qty Issued").Value / countMonths
            rows.Cells("Ave").Value = Format(ave, "0.00")
Next
```

Comment: @nempoBu4 Still having the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just try it this way

```
rows.Cells("Ave").Value = Format((dgView.Rows(0).Cells("Qty Issued")).Value / countMonths).ToString
```

but you should be aware that you are always taking the first row for `"Qty Issued"`

if it's a row by row average i would suggest using

```
rows.Cells("Ave").Value = Format((rows.Cells("Qty Issued")).Value / countMonths).ToString
```

and btw u are not really formatting anything this way ... you could also write this

```
rows.Cells("Ave").Value = dgView.Rows(0).Cells("Qty Issued").Value / countMonths
```

the outcome is the same.

and don't forget to check if the values are `DBNULL.Value` or `0`

Comment: Thanks. I somewhat did the same.